# How to backup NAS to SpiderOak cloud

Tags: linux, backup, nas, spideroak

I have a Debian Linux based NAS (network attached storage) from [Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS216+II) that holds movies, music, photos etc...

The NAS is running the latest `DSM 6` firmware built on an Intel x64 processor.  I would like to setup an automatic backup job to [SpiderOak cloud](https://spideroak.com/solutions/spideroak-one).

Problem is that there is [very little information](https://spideroak.com/faq/will-spideroak-work-on-a-nas-device) I could find. SpiderOak basically suggests backing up the NAS by mounting it as an external drive on your PC, as you would backup a USB key.  This is problematic for several reasons:

- Only works if your PC is on and on the same network as the NAS
- Data flows from *NAS >> Router >> PC >> Router >> Cloud* unnecessarily clogging your LAN and using your PC resources. Ideally it would just be *NAS >> Router >> Cloud*
- Typically, several computers share a NAS; setting NAS and PC data as being from the same device will overly complicate matters when the time comes to restore data

If you successfully linked any NAS to SpiderOak, please share how you did it here. Even if it's a different NAS, I bet people will find it helpful.  If we get good feedback, I'll bring this resource to the attention of SpiderOak support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## To setup SpiderOak 6 on Synology NAS running DSM 6 firmware

### Foreword

The steps below were run on a *Synology DS216+* running *DSM 6.0.2*, but would probably work on other NASes running Linux with small modifications.  The SpiderOak version used was 6.1.3

I relied heavily on [this page](http://www.joshpruett.com/2015/02/spideroak.html) and [this page](http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=31037) as starting points.

Some things to note:

- These instructions work as of November 2016.
- Whenever instructions ask you to execute or run a command, they are referring to SSH (more info below). All SSH commands below should be performed as the *root* user. I suggest trying to understand what each command does before running it.
- The packages you should install depend on your CPU architecture. You can find out yours by executing `dpkg --print-architecture` in SSH.
- If you know why step 26 below fails or how to fix it, please share!

### Enable SSH

1. Login to DSM (your NAS' web dashboard) by going to `http:<NAS-IP-ADDRESS>`
2. Within DSM, open `Control Panel >> Terminal & SNMP`
3. Check `Enable SSH service`

### SSH into your NAS

4. Get an SSH client (I used [Putty SSH for Windows](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html); Macs have a built-in SSH client: Terminal)
5. Find your NAS’ LAN IP address and SSH port. The IP is visible within DSM at `Control Panel >> Info Center >> Network tab`.  The SSH port is 22 by default.
6. Use the IP and port to connect via SSH. Use the DSM login creds.
7. In SSH execute: `sudo -i` to become root user. You will need to provide the admin password once more. For details, see [this FAQ](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_login_to_DSM_with_root_permission_via_SSH_Telnet)

### Install Entware-ng (opkg package manager)

8. From SSH, follow [these instructions](https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS) to install the opkg package manager.
   a. To determine the right version to install, run `dpkg --print-architecture`. For instance, *amd64* means you need version *x86 64-bit*.

   b. The instructions that require you to edit files can be accomplished by using the Vim editor. For example, to edit */etc/rc.local*, run `vi /etc/rc.local`. Here's [a quick intro to Vim](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/Editors/ViIntro.html)

   c.  For *DSM 6* firmware, when the *Entware-ng* instructions ask you to edit */root/.profile*,  edit */etc/profile* instead
9. Restart the NAS, log into SSH and run `sudo -i` to become root user
10. Run `opkg install nano` to get an easier text editor than Vim.

### Install SpiderOakOne

11. Go to [SpiderOak website](https://spideroak.com/opendownload) to get the URL to the installation package that matches your device. My NAS has a 64-bit processor so I chose Linux Debian 64-bit and my `PACKAGE-URL` is `https://spideroak.com/getbuild?platform=ubuntu&arch=x86_64`
12. Run: `cd /root` to open the root directory
13. Run: `wget –output-document=spideroak.install.deb <YOUR-PACKAGE-URL>` to download and save the package
14. Once you get notice that *spideroak.install.deb* has been saved, press `Ctr+c` to return to the prompt.
15. Run: `dpkg-deb -x spideroak.install.deb SpiderOakONE` to extract the downloaded files into the */root/SpiderOakONE* directory
16. Run: `rm spideroak.install.deb` to delete the downloaded package
17. Run: `mv SpiderOakONE /opt/SpiderOakONE` to move program files to */opt*
18. Run: `sed -i /opt/SpiderOakONE/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE -e s+/opt/SpiderOakONE+/opt/SpiderOakONE/opt/SpiderOakONE+` This fixes paths in SpiderOak’s startup script to point to the correct path from step 17. To do this manually instead, open */opt/SpiderOakONE/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE* and replace all instances of */opt/SpiderOakONE* in the file with */opt/SpiderOakONE/opt/SpiderOakONE*
19. If you plan to backup a lot of data, the SpiderOak data folder will grow large during backups. In my case this filled the system partition and stopped the NAS from working properly.  To fix this, I moved the data folder to the general partition where all my data is stored: */volume1*

    a. Run: `mkdir /volume1/SpiderOakONE` to create a new data directory. Replace */volume1* with whatever your general data partition is.

    b. Run: `ln -s /volume1/SpiderOakONE/ /root/.config/SpiderOakONE` to create a symlink so that accessing the old */root* location will be automatically redirect to the new

### Add NAS to SpiderOak Account

20. Run: `ln -s /opt/SpiderOakONE/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE /opt/bin/spideroak` to create a symlink redirecting */opt/bin/spideroak* to the program's real path. This allows us to run the program by simply entering `spideroak` in SSH instead of having to type the full path.
21. Run: `spideroak --help` to see the options available. If that command returns *“command not found”* step 20 did not work as intended. You could instead run the program using its full path: `/opt/SpiderOakONE/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE –-help`.
22. Run: `spideroak --setup=-` to register your NAS with the service. You’ll need your SpiderOak username and password

### Basic commands

23. Run: `spideroak --include-dir=<PATH>` to add a directory to the backup set.  Example of path might be `/volume1/Pictures`. `--exclude-dir=<PATH>` can be used instead to exclude certain directories. If the path includes spaces, you must wrap it in double-quotes.
24. To see what is currently selected for backup, run `spideroak --selection`; run `spideroak --reset-selection` to reset.
25. To run a backup job, run: `spideroak --batchmode` You can add `--redirect=<FILE_PATH>` argument if you wish to generate a log file. The backup will be interrupted if your SSH connection is broken (eg: your PC goes on standby) so I suggest scheduling backups to be executed as cron jobs by the NAS itself (see next section)

### Setup a backup schedule

26. DSM (web control panel) includes the ability to schedule tasks to be run regularly in `Control Panel >> Task Scheduler`.  We should be able to use this to schedule regular backups with a command such as `spideroak --batchmode` but even though this command works when running SSH as root, it fails when Task Scheduler tries to run it as root. I don’t know why.  Instead I edited the crontab (the schedule) manually through SSH.
27. Look around for how to edit the crontab on your NAS.  On mine, the following 4 steps apply:
28. System scheduled tasks are stored in the file */etc/crontab*.  Run `cp /etc/crontab /etc/crontab.bak` to create a backup copy. If something goes wrong with the crontab edits later, restore from the working backup with `cp /etc/crontab.bak /etc/crontab`
29. Run: `nano /etc/crontab` to open the schedule for editing. Nano text editor was installed in step 10. A quick web search will give tips on how to format *crontab*. For example to run a backup job at 10:30pm each night, add this line to the file:

`30        22        *        *        *        root        spideroak --batchmode`

Columns must be separated by tabs, not spaces.  If the command fails to execute, replace `spideroak` with its full path (see step 21).  To log the results, add the argument `--redirect=<FILEPATH>` and Spideroak will write a log at that path.

30. If you want to just test whether things work without having to wait for a lengthy backup to complete, replace `--batchmode` with a much shorter process such as  `--selection` and check the log for the result
31. Finally, check whether your edits survive a system restart.  Restart the NAS, log into SSH, run `sudo -i` to become root, and `nano /etc/crontab` to inspect the schedule.

**You've done it!**

### Troubleshooting & Tips

1. If in SSH, you get the error *“command not found”* for a command that used to work, it may be because */opt/bin* or */opt/sbin* are not in the PATH:

   a.  Run `vi /etc/profile` and edit the PATH section of the file (add `:/opt/bin:opt/sbin` at the end of the PATH string)

   b.  Restart the NAS
2. If you run SpiderOak and get *“Command line arguments not allowed during New User Setup”*, it’s likely because the symlink we created in step 19.b was destroyed, so Spideroak can’t find its data folder. Redo 19.b.
3. If your installation gets corrupted, you can re-initialize your device to the server with `spideroak --setup=-`. This may take a while because after setup the program will immediately complete a backup if needed: took my NAS 12hrs.
4. I had to factory-reset the NAS once, and so this setup was partially lost. To get things working after a reset, I had to redo step 8.b, 19.b, 20, reboot, and re-create the cron job (steps 26 to 31)
5. If an SSH command fails with an error about permissions, execute `whoami`. If the result doesn't say *"root"*, run `sudo -i` to become root (you will need your DSM password)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a docker solution:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jandebleser/spideroak/

https://github.com/jandebleser/spideroak

The main problem was that in the Docker application on the Synology server, you can not pass command line arguments.

You have to create a config.json file with your username, password and devicename.
Mount this file, and the folder you want to backup.
Then, start the container to do nothing by setting the environmental variable SLEEP to "infinity". Then go into the Terminal tab, start a bash command, and run

```
SpiderOakONE --setup=/config.json
SpiderOakONE --include-dir=/backup
```

For normal operation, set the SLEEP variable to 0, and restart.